# Finding the position of an element within a nested list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

For example:

```
?- position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],c,P)
P=1
?- position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],g,P)
P=2 
?- position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],b,P)
P=0
```

I've been looking at the nth0/3 predicate but I'm not sure if that is the right way to go about this. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

I'm trying to find the position of each element *within* its nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

**1.** The first position predicate is the base case (Stopping Condition if Element not found keep checking till list is empty).

**2.** The second predicate takes the list, Element to be checked, and give the final position in P.  Using if-else technique. If Element is a member of H (meaning H=[b,c,f]) then give us the position of the Element using nth0. Else, check the remaining T (Tail: [[a,d,g],[h,e]]) in the same manner.

```
position([],_,_).
position([H|T],Element,P):-
    (   member(Element,H)->  
        nth0(P,H,Element);
        position(T,Element,P)).
```

**Example:**

```
?-position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],c,P).
P = 1
false
?-position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],e,P).
P = 1
?-position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],g,P).
P = 2
?-position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],b,P).
P = 0
false
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Shouldn't the example with 'e' return P = 1? Since that is its position in its list? I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Joe e is giving  1.

Answer (score 1):

```
position(LL,E,N):-
    nth1(N,LL,L),
    member(E,L).

?- position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],c,P).
P = 1 ;
false.

?- position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],g,P).
P = 2 ;
false.
```

Assuming you are allowed to use `member/2` and `nth1/3`, see their implementation below.

The predicate just goes through all members `L` of the inputlist `LL` through `nth1/3` (and tracks the position `N`) and checks if your searched element `E` is a member of the list `L`.

This predicate works for simple nested lists where the searched element is direct member of the sublist. It will **not** work for further nested sublosts, example: `position([[b,c,f],[[a],[d,g]],[h,e]],g,P)`

In case you are not allowed to use inbuild predicates:

```
my_nth1(1,[X|_],X).
my_nth1(Idx,[_|List],X) :-
    my_nth1(Idx1,List,X),
    Idx is Idx1+1.

my_member(X, [X|_]). 
my_member(X, [_|T]):- 
    my_member(X, T).
```

You could even not use the member predicate by just writing

```
position(LL,E,N):-
    mynth1(N,LL,L),
    mynth1(_,L,E).
```

---

In case you are not interested in the number of the sublist but the number of the element within the sublist:

```
position(LL,E,N):-
    member(L,LL),
    nth0(N,L,E).

?- position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],c,P).
P = 1 ; 
false.

?- position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],g,P).
P = 2 ;
false.
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my question. I was hoping to find the position of the element within the nested lists (i.e. b = 0, c = 1, f = 2). Your solution works great for finding which list it is in though. I'm sorry about the confusion, I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Joe fixed the issue. I was wondering why you want to use nth0/3 if you clearly needed nth1/3 xD